# Restore MS SQL database

Tags: sql-server, docker, octopus-deploy

I am trying to restore a Microsoft Server SQL database running in centos throw a dockerized instance.

I have 5 databases (OctopusDeploy, master, model, msdb, and tempdb) but tempdb cannot be backed up.

To get the backup I run the following commands:

```
sudo docker exec -it $db_container_name /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd    -S localhost -U SA -P 'N0tS3cr3t!'    -Q "BACKUP DATABASE [OctopusDeploy] TO DISK = N'/var/opt/mssql/backup/db_OctopusDeploy.bak' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT, NAME = 'Octopus-Deploy-full', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, STATS = 10"
sudo docker exec -it $db_container_name /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd    -S localhost -U SA -P 'N0tS3cr3t!'    -Q "BACKUP DATABASE [master] TO DISK = N'/var/opt/mssql/backup/db_master.bak' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT, NAME = 'master-full', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, STATS = 10"
sudo docker exec -it $db_container_name /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd    -S localhost -U SA -P 'N0tS3cr3t!'    -Q "BACKUP DATABASE [model] TO DISK = N'/var/opt/mssql/backup/db_model.bak' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT, NAME = 'model-full', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, STATS = 10"
sudo docker exec -it $db_container_name /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd    -S localhost -U SA -P 'N0tS3cr3t!'    -Q "BACKUP DATABASE [msdb] TO DISK = N'/var/opt/mssql/backup/db_msdb.bak' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT, NAME = 'msdb-full', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, STATS = 10"
```

This commands generates the files db_OctopusDeploy.bak, db_master.bak...

After that, I remove the database I restart the server and I execute the following commands in order to restore the database (Before this commands I execute another comands in order to transfer the .bak files to /var/opt/mssql/backup/ inside the docker):

```
sudo docker exec -it $db_container_name /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P 'N0tS3cr3t!' -Q "RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = '/var/opt/mssql/backup/$db_octopus'"  | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 1-2
sudo docker exec -it $db_container_name /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P 'N0tS3cr3t!' -Q "RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = '/var/opt/mssql/backup/$db_master'"  | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 1-2
sudo docker exec -it $db_container_name /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P 'N0tS3cr3t!' -Q "RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = '/var/opt/mssql/backup/$db_model'"  | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 1-2
sudo docker exec -it $db_container_name /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P 'N0tS3cr3t!' -Q "RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = '/var/opt/mssql/backup/$db_msdb'"  | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 1-2


sudo docker exec -it $db_container_name /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P 'N0tS3cr3t!' -Q "USE master"
echo "USE master"
sudo docker exec -it $db_container_name /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P 'N0tS3cr3t!' -Q "ALTER DATABASE OctopusDeploy SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE"
echo "Alter OctopusDeploy"
sudo docker exec -it $db_container_name /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P 'N0tS3cr3t!' -Q "ALTER DATABASE master SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE"
echo "Alter master"
sudo docker exec -it $db_container_name /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P 'N0tS3cr3t!' -Q "ALTER DATABASE model SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE"
echo "Alter model"
sudo docker exec -it $db_container_name /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P 'N0tS3cr3t!' -Q "ALTER DATABASE msdb SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE"
echo "Alter msdb"

sudo docker exec -it $db_container_name /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P 'N0tS3cr3t!' -Q "RESTORE DATABASE OctopusDeploy FROM DISK = '/var/opt/mssql/backup/$db_octopus' WITH MOVE 'OctopusDeploy' TO '/var/opt/mssql/data/OctopusDeploy.mdf', MOVE 'OctopusDeploy_log' TO '/var/opt/mssql/data/OctopusDeploy_log.ldf'"
sudo docker exec -it $db_container_name /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P 'N0tS3cr3t!' -Q "RESTORE DATABASE master FROM DISK = '/var/opt/mssql/backup/$db_master' WITH MOVE 'master' TO '/var/opt/mssql/data/master.mdf', MOVE 'mastlog' TO '/var/opt/mssql/data/mastlog.ldf'"
sudo docker exec -it $db_container_name /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P 'N0tS3cr3t!' -Q "RESTORE DATABASE model FROM DISK = '/var/opt/mssql/backup/$db_model' WITH MOVE 'modeldev' TO '/var/opt/mssql/data/model.mdf', MOVE 'modellog' TO '/var/opt/mssql/data/modellog.ldf'"
sudo docker exec -it $db_container_name /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P 'N0tS3cr3t!' -Q "RESTORE DATABASE msdb FROM DISK = '/var/opt/mssql/backup/$db_msdb' WITH MOVE 'MSDBData' TO '/var/opt/mssql/data/MSDBData.mdf', MOVE 'MSDBLog' TO '/var/opt/mssql/data/MSDBLog.ldf'"

sudo docker exec -it $db_container_name /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P 'N0tS3cr3t!' -Q "ALTER DATABASE OctopusDeploy SET MULTI_USER"
sudo docker exec -it $db_container_name /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P 'N0tS3cr3t!' -Q "ALTER DATABASE master SET MULTI_USER"
sudo docker exec -it $db_container_name /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P 'N0tS3cr3t!' -Q "ALTER DATABASE model SET MULTI_USER"
sudo docker exec -it $db_container_name /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P 'N0tS3cr3t!' -Q "ALTER DATABASE msdb SET MULTI_USER"
```

The log that I get for executing the above is the following:

```
Changed database context to 'master'.
USE master
Nonqualified transactions are being rolled back. Estimated rollback completion: 0%.
Nonqualified transactions are being rolled back. Estimated rollback completion: 100%.
Alter OctopusDeploy
Msg 5058, Level 16, State 5, Server 9453f1d192ea, Line 1
Option 'SINGLE_USER' cannot be set in database 'master'.
Alter master
Alter model
Alter msdb
Msg 3154, Level 16, State 4, Server 9453f1d192ea, Line 1
The backup set holds a backup of a database other than the existing 'OctopusDeploy' database.
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Server 9453f1d192ea, Line 1
RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
Msg 3108, Level 16, State 1, Server 9453f1d192ea, Line 1
To restore the master database, the server must be running in single-user mode. For information on starting in single-user mode, see "How to: Start an Instance of SQL Server (sqlservr.exe)" in Books Online.
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Server 9453f1d192ea, Line 1
RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
Msg 3159, Level 16, State 1, Server 9453f1d192ea, Line 1
The tail of the log for the database "model" has not been backed up. Use BACKUP LOG WITH NORECOVERY to backup the log if it contains work you do not want to lose. Use the WITH REPLACE or WITH STOPAT clause of the RESTORE statement to just overwrite the contents of the log.
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Server 9453f1d192ea, Line 1
RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
Processed 1760 pages for database 'msdb', file 'MSDBData' on file 1.
Processed 2 pages for database 'msdb', file 'MSDBLog' on file 1.
RESTORE DATABASE successfully processed 1762 pages in 0.023 seconds (598.335 MB/sec).
Msg 1205, Level 13, State 68, Server 9453f1d192ea, Line 1
Transaction (Process ID 54) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.
Msg 5069, Level 16, State 1, Server 9453f1d192ea, Line 1
ALTER DATABASE statement failed.
Msg 5058, Level 16, State 5, Server 9453f1d192ea, Line 1
Option 'MULTI_USER' cannot be set in database 'master'.
octopus_db
octopus
```

So it seems that the msdb database is recovered sucesfully but not the other 3 What I'm doing wrong?

From what I have seen the important database is OctopusDeploy so the recovery of this would be enough for me.

Comment: Instead of executing *multiple* independent queries, just execute a single script. The very fact that the queries you used are hidden outside the page is a very strong indication that something is wrong

Comment: Right now, you are running multiple long-running queries without ever waiting for them to complete. They end up blocking each other

Comment: I just updated the scripts as they are cutted, the think is that the first part is just to enter inside the docker, I don't think that the problem is becouse i'm running queries without wating because the script doesn't execut the next command until the last one finishes